# Jquery filter syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to filter a set of links against an array and then style those not in the array as unavaible, how would I do that.

Here is what I have:

```
if (this.id == '93') {
     $links.filter(function() {

   }).addClass('unavailable');
```

But I don't know how the syntax for checking against an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The short answer...

Use [jQuery's `$.inArray(value, array)` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Also, see this Stackoverflow question, [Javascript - array.contains(obj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj), whose answer mentions jQuery's `$.inArray` function as well as array searching functions in other JavaScript libraries.

#### The long answer...

I presume you have an collection of hyperlinks on your page, like so:

```
<p><a id="google" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></p>
<p><a id="yahoo" href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo!</a></p>
<p><a id="ask" href="http://www.ask.com/">Ask</a></p>
<p><a id="icerocket" href="http://www.icerocket.com/">Icerocket</a></p>
```

And that you have an array that contains the `id`s of those hyperlinks, like so:

```
var validLinkIds = ["google", "ask"];
```

The following script will filter across all `<a>` elements, "disabling" those that are *not* in the `validLinkIds` array:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), validLinkIds) < 0)
            $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

I created a JSFiddle entry where you can run/test out this script - http://jsfiddle.net/qMhWQ/

Happy Programming!